# I can not access localhost on other devices on my router

Tags: apache, server, localhost

Good morning,

Today I tried to set up a Apache 2 server on Ubuntu 18.4 LTS, and yet while the localhost page works fine on my browser, it does not show the web page on any other devices. Why will it not display

(P.S. I am a beginner at networking, so if this is a dumb question, please just let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localhost` always points to the "local machine". To access the Apache server from a second computer, you'll need to use the IP address for it.

For example, if the Apache server's IP is 192.168.123.456, you would use http://192.168.123.456 from the second computer. If you went to http://localhost on the second computer, it would be looking for a web server on that second computer.